# printing a list and removing the '\n' from each new line, giving error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Printing a list from a file and not allowing me to use `.rstrip('/n')`:

```
path =('debits.txt','r')


 f = open('debits.txt')
 read = f.readlines().rstrip('/n')
```

expecting me to print a nice clean list without the `'\n'` and each entry put into a list.

Comment: Hi, what error?

Comment: attribute error

Answer (score 1):

First, `readlines` returns a list, so you need to apply `rstrip` to its elements, not to it, and, you're striping `'/n'` in your code (should be `'\n'`), finally, you're not using the `path` variable in `open` (not using it will not cause an error but you probably should use it since you defined it):

```
path =('a.txt', 'r')

with open(*path) as f:  #  use `with` to automatically close the file after reading
    read = [l.rstrip('\n') for l in f.readlines()]
```

One more note, you can just use `l.rstrip()` (no need for `'\n'`) to remove whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

`rstrip()` removes `\n` from strings not a list. That's why you are getting error.
Use this while reading file:

```
with open('debits.txt') as f:
    alist = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

f.readlines() returns a list so iterate through that list instead:

```
f = open('debits.txt', 'r')
read = f.readlines()
for line in read:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    print(line)
f.close()
```